# resize text on overflow in CSS/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I'm developing a head mounted display device, and I'm planning to use a web UI for it.  I want the text on the screen to start out very large and resize if there is too much to fit on the screen.  I've looked around the web for a good solution, but I couldn't find anything.  I plan to use Firefox.

Comment: This? http://www.sitepoint.com/auto-text-fill-resize-plugins/

Comment: Number 4 looked promising, but the link is broken.

Comment: Use this http://www.geekymonkey.com/programming/jquery/TextFill/jquery-textFill-0.1.js

Comment: Looks good!  Thank you so much.  BTW I found the official site: http://jquery-textfill.github.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this need, you can use [jQuery TextFill](http://jquery-textfill.github.io/) to adapt to your container. You just need the following code:

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.textfill.min.js"></script>

<div id="my-element" style="width:100px; height:50px;">
    <span>My awesome text!</span>
</div>

$('#my-element').textfill({
    ...options...
});
```